# Error readLine() Java read wrong line

Tags: java, linked-list, readline

I'm new to Java and I'm experiencing an error that's blowing my mind...the error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at BancA.carica(BancA.java:30)
    at BancA.main(BancA.java:46)
```

I need to load some values from a txt file...this is composed by a ID (Cliente1 etc), a first list of number(payments) and a second one (transfers)...I've decided to distinguish these two categories dividing them through a "-"...but readLine() seems to read the wrong line, or ignoring my "while" statement...anyway, this is my code, your help we'll be so appreciated :-)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class BancA{
    private static final String CLIENTI = ("Clienti.txt");
    private static ArrayList <Conto> conto = new ArrayList <Conto>();
    public static void carica(){
        BufferedReader bc;
        Conto co = new Conto();
        String tmp, tmp1, tmp2;
        try{
            bc = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(CLIENTI));
            tmp = bc.readLine();
            while(tmp!=null){
            co.setId(tmp);
            tmp1 = bc.readLine();
            while(!(tmp1.equals("-"))){
                co.setBonifico(Integer.parseInt(tmp1));
                tmp1 = bc.readLine();
            }
            tmp2 = bc.readLine();
            while(!(tmp2.equals("-"))){
                co.setVersamento(Integer.parseInt(tmp2));
                tmp2 = bc.readLine();
            }
                conto.add(co);
                co = new Conto();
                tmp = bc.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println(conto);
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
public static void main(String [] args){
    carica();
}
}
```

and this is the other class:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Conto{
public String id;
public LinkedList <Integer> bonifico = new LinkedList <Integer>();
public LinkedList <Integer> versamento = new LinkedList <Integer>();
public Conto(){
}
public void setId(String i){
    id = i;
}
public void setBonifico(int b){
    bonifico.add(b);
}
public void setVersamento(int v){
    versamento.add(v);
}
public String getId(){
    return id;
}
public LinkedList <Integer> getBonifico(){
    return bonifico;
}
public LinkedList <Integer> getVersamento(){
    return versamento;
}
public String toString(){
    String str = ("\nId: " +id+ "\nBonifico: " +bonifico+ "\nVersamento:+versamento);
    return str;
}
 }
```

while this is my Clienti.txt file:

```
 Cliente1
 1
 2
 3
 -
 41
 52
 33
 90
 -
 Cliente2
 4
 -
 89
 3
 1
```

Comment: ANd where is line 30?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `readline()` can encounter the EOF, and `tmp2` can be `null` in this situation, which causes the `NullPointerException`.

Changing `while(!(tmp2.equals("-")))` to `while (tmp2 != null && !tmp2.equals("-"))` solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds, like the file is not found. is your file really located in the same directory as the .jar/.class file?

you should pass a File-object to your FileReader, not a string. so you can check, if you chose the right path by calling

```
myFile.exists();
```

(->should return true)

Answer (score 0):

[image: EOF reached - NULL]

You need to put a check in there for the EOF. Right now, you're throwing a NullPointerException because you're at the end of the file and you are expecting to see a '-' there. The while loop doesn't know what to do and it can't exit properly.

The while loop should have an OR condition to say either "-" or EOF. Even an "if" clause to check if the EOF has been reached. If so, then continue.

EDIT: I just saw Siyu Song comment and he's correct. `while (tmp2 != null && !tmp2.equals("-"))` will work. I just tried it out now and it worked like a charm.